# Line $mx + ny = 3$ is normal to the hyperbola $x^2 – y^2 = 1$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

If the line $mx + ny = 3$ is normal to the hyperbola $x^2 – y^2 = 1$, then evaluate $\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}$.

I compared given equation of normal to equation of normal at parametric point i.e
$x\sin\theta+y=2\tan\theta$ and obtained $\frac{1}{m^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{4}{9}$ but can't use it to obtain $\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Remember that the line has to touch the hyperbola at some point as well.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a flaw in the text, expression $\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}$, should have been $\frac{1}{m^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Let us see why:

First of all, I confirm the expression given by @Mathematician :

$$\frac{1}{m^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{4}{9} \ \ \ (1)$$

Proof below.

In fact, as the question is formulated, the only reasonable answer should have been "$\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}$ is *this* constant". But  due to (1),

$$\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{4}{9}+\frac{2}{n^2}$$

which is a variable quantity.

**Proof of (1)**: The equation of the tangent line $(T)$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ is $xx_0-yy_0=1 \ \ (2)$.

Straight line $(D_{mn})$ with equation $mx+ny=1$ must fillful two conditions:

- $(D_{mn})$ and $(T)$ should be orthogonal, i.e., their normal vectors $(x_0,-y_0)$ and $(m,n)$ are orthogonal, i.e., $mx_0-ny_0=0 \ \ (3)$
- $(D_{mn})$ must pass through point $(x_0,y_0)$, i.e., $mx_0+ny_0=3 \ \ (4)$

Solving the system constituted by (3) and (4) for $x_0$ and $y_0$, we get:

$$x_0=\frac{3}{2m} \ \  and  \ \ y_0=\frac{3}{2n} $$

Finally using constraint $x_0^2-y_0^2=1$, we obtain condition (1).